# How to display query based on condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I know this is simple but I still wonder why I don't get the output that I want:

```
SELECT 
    name, amount, status
FROM 
    asdfg
WHERE 
    status = '1' 
    AND Type = 'P' 
    AND id = 'O10' OR id = 'OM1' OR id = 'OM6'
```

but I got result like this which is wrong. How do I make sure that only result with `status = 1`  can be displayed not `0`?

```
name  | amount | status
------+--------+-------
 lili |   35   |  0
 opi  |   47   |  0 
 moss |   14   |  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a logic precedence issue. `AND` has priority over `OR`, so you need to put the `OR` condition in parentheses:

```
WHERE status = '1' 
  AND Type = 'P' 
  AND (id = 'O10' OR id = 'OM1' OR id = 'OM6')
```

Better yet, use `IN`:

```
WHERE status = '1' 
  AND Type = 'P' 
  AND id IN ('O10', 'OM1', 'OM6')
```

Comment: @willu: because it is logically equivalent to `OR` in this context, and yet simpler to write and follow  - and you don't have to worry about operators precedence anymore.

Comment: i see ! fully understood now thank you. will accept your answer in 7 minutes. thank you for explaining :)